# can't connect to internet with quectel m95

Tags: serial-port, gsm, at-command, windows-10-iot-core

I'm at the moment trying to connect my gsm 2 click shield using a quectel m95 to internet using my raspberry pi 3 on windows 10 iot.
To do that, I tried 2 methods:
first I tried with http protocol using this functions:

```
-AT+QIFGCNT=0                            ==>OK
-AT+QICSGP=1,"CMNET"                     ==>OK
-AT+QIREGAPP                             ==>OK
-AT+QIACT                                ==>ERROR
-AT+QHTTPURL=urlLenght,MaxInputTime
-Put the website                         ==>CME ERROR: 3810
```

I tried with GPRS too:

```
-AT+CGATT?                              ==>OK
-AT + CGDCONT = 1,"IP","gprs.oi.com.br" ==>OK
-AT+CGACT=1,1                           ==>CME error 100
-AT+CGATT=1                             ==>OK
-AT+QIDNSIP=1                           ==>OK
-AT+QIOPEN="mode","IP_adress","port"\n  ==>CME error 100
```

I don't understant why it doesn't work... Can somebody help me?
thank you

Comment: Can you show the results of the following commands?
`AT+CPIN?`
`AT+COPS?`
`AT+CREG?`
`AT+CGREG?`
`AT+CGATT?`
`AT+CGACT?`

Comment: Here are the results: 

`
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
==>
OK
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"SFR"
==>
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1
==>
OK
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 0
==>
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,0

+CGACT: 2,0

+CGACT: 3,0
==>
OK`

Comment: For your "CGDCONT" command, you should perhaps specify the username and password.  For instance:

```AT + CGDCONT = 1,"IP","gprs.oi.com.br","",""``` for no username and password.  Let me know how that  goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your "CGDCONT" command, you should perhaps specify the username and password.  For instance:

`AT + CGDCONT = 1,"IP","gprs.oi.com.br","",""` for no username and password.  Let me know how that  goes.

Alternatively,  in the `QIREGAPP` case, you also need to specify the APN, username, and password.  For instance:

`AT+QIREGAPP="gprs.oi.com.br","",""`

Please update your commands as above (including APN, username, and password in both CGDCONT and QIREGAPP) and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Also, I'm essentially pulling some of this content from the Quectel "[Recommended TCP/IP Process App Note](http://www.antrax.de/downloads/gsm-easy!/quectel-application%20notes/gsm_tcpip_an_v1.1.pdf)"

Comment: here are the resuts for QIREGAPP: 'AT+QIFGCNT=0
OK
AT+QICSGP=1,"CMNET"
OK
AT+QIREGAPP="gprs.oi.com.br","",""
ERROR
AT+QIACT
ERROR'                **for CGDCONT:** AT+QIFGCNT=0
OK
AT+QICSGP=1,"CMNET"
OK
AT+QIREGAPP
ERROR
AT+QIACT
ERROR
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 0

OK
AT + CGDCONT = 1,"IP","gprs.oi.com.br","",""
ERROR
AT+CGACT=1,1
+CME ERROR: 100
AT+CGATT=1
+CME ERROR: 100    I'll check on my own the document you talk about to maybe find a solution

Comment: When i try the command `AT+QISTAT`the state is `IP IND` meaning that the gprs context is activating but it never ends...

Comment: QICSGP of CMNET is incorrect for your configuration, you arent using the CMNET APN.  You need to specify the full APN, username, and password for QICSGP, e.g. 'AT+QICSGP=1,"gprs.oi.com.br","",""

Comment: when i power up my shield, the state is:  `CGDCONT: 1,"IP","sl2sfr","",0,0`  `QNSTATUT:0` `QINISTAT:3`  `CSQ: 22,0` `state:IP INITIAL` `CGREG:0,3`      And when I try to open the connection:  'AT+QIFGCNT=0 ==>OK` `AT+QICSGP=1,"websfr"`,"","" ==>OK`  `AT+QIMUX=0 ==>OK` ` AT+QIMODE=0  ==>OK`  AT+QIREGAPP="`websfr","",""` `AT+QIACT==>ERROR`

Comment: Other point i'm asking myself:  I did a little inversion of polarity but not too long. Do you think it's possible that it damaged tcp/ip part? Is there a way to check hardware integrity? Thanks for your help

Comment: If youre making it as far as your notes suggest, I think it unlikely to be hardware.  Why does your specified APN keep changing? Is it websfr, sl2sfr, or gprs.oi.com.br?  It cant be all of these at the same time.  This depends on the specific sim card youre using , the command will change depending on the APN/SIM.  Please indicate the details of your SIM and APN.

Comment: at the begining of the problem i was not sure about the apn to use but today I checked the APN on a tablet and it's "websfr" or sl2sfr. I put websfr everywhere on my code. But there are still no changes... What details do you need on the sim card?

Comment: If you see "CGREG 0,3" it unfortunately means that the network has blocked/denied your SIM from establishing a GPRS (data) registration.  If you see CGREG 0,3 with all APNs, you wont be able to connect for GPRS data purposes.  Additionally, if you plan to use 'QIACT' you must first enter the command (with appropriate parameters) QIREGAPP

Comment: I tryed to use another sim card and it is now working. Thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

For my case the problem was in the APN name. As it turns out although I was connected to "Orange" network, my sim card was from "Telit Iot" and I needed to set the APN for that "internetm2m.air.com" using `AT+QICSGP=1,"internetm2m.air.com","","",0`
After that change I was able to connect using the following:

```
/* Use AT+QICSGP=1,"INTERNETM2M.AIR.COM","","",0 to set APN as "INTERNETM2M.AIR.COM",user name as "",password as "" */
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:499_S:] AT+QICSGP=1,"INTERNETM2M.AIR.COM","","",0
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:511_R:] AT+QICSGP=1,"INTERNETM2M.AIR.COM","","",0

[2017-02-07 14:03:32:517_R:] OK

/* (4) Start TCPIP task */
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:544_S:] AT+QIREGAPP
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:559_R:] AT+QIREGAPP

[2017-02-07 14:03:32:560_R:] OK

/* Check the current connecting mode(1: GPRS connecting mode£¬0: CSD connecting mode) */
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:584_S:] AT+QICSGP?
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:592_R:] AT+QICSGP?

[2017-02-07 14:03:32:594_R:] +QICSGP: 1

[2017-02-07 14:03:32:594_R:] OK

/* The current connecting mode is GPRS connecting mode */

/* Active the GPRS context */
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:626_S:] AT+QIACT
[2017-02-07 14:03:32:640_R:] AT+QIACT

[2017-02-07 14:03:33:343_R:] OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to connect my GPRS module to the internet using hologram as mine APN. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694991/mqtt-library-on-microcontroller) and [this](https://epos.lisha.ufsc.br/GSM+GPRS+Quectel+M95) I used the following commands in the presented order and worked just fine for me:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","hologram"
AT+CGACT=1,1
AT+CGATT=1
AT+QIDNSIP=1
AT+QICSGP=1,"hologram","","",0
AT+QIREGAPP?
AT+QIOPEN="TCP","tarcis.io",80
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been communicating M95 with multiple MSP430 and ARM MCUs. However, in your case you can pull in the commands as my code is done in CCS. This is a tested one:
(standard replies are omitted. They are as mentioned in their datasheet)
1. AT+QIFGCNT=0\r
2. AT+QICSGP=1,"www"\r --> (note that instead of CMNET as given in their datasheet, provide)
                         (your operator's APN)
3. AT+QHTTPURL=36,30\r
4. http://www.turjasuzowrld.in\r
5. AT+QHTTPGET=60\r
6. AT+QHTTPREAD=30\r
7. AT+QIDEACT\r

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit point 4 as it is linked to your webpage and it is not clear.

Comment: The reason why i added point 4 is to just show that i had checked the GET API with my website. The user can use any website they want, i dont have any intention of advertizing my website here!